# prove arbitrary intersection of open set can be closed, especially for the counterexample equality holds

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

When I search online for an arbitrary union of closed sets need not be closed and the arbitrary intersection of open sets need not be open, we have below respectively(let's say $b-a>3$). I can get the idea by observation, but I cannot prove how that equality holds

$$\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}[a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}]=(a,b)\\\bigcap^\infty_{n=1}(a-\frac{1}{n},b+\frac{1}{n})=[a,b]$$

Genuinely asking for help, thanks

---

In response to the @Alex G. reverse inclusion:

If I could prove the claim is that sufficient to prove the reverse inclusion: $\forall\epsilon>0,x<b$ if and only if $x\leq b-\epsilon$, and similarly for left part $x>a$.

necessity is straight forward: $x\leq b-\epsilon<b$

sufficiency by contradiction: suppose $x>b-\epsilon\iff\epsilon>b-x$.

we know $x<b\iff\frac{b-x}{2}>0$. Substitute $\epsilon=\frac{b-x}{2}>b-x\iff\frac{1}{2}>1$ contradition built.

---

$\forall \epsilon>0,x>a$ if and only if $x\geq a+\epsilon$

$\Longleftarrow  x\geq a+\epsilon>a$

$\Longrightarrow $ suppose $x<a+\epsilon\iff x-a<\epsilon$. we know $\frac{x-a}{2}>0$ from $x>a$ So that $x-a<\frac{x-a}{2}$. Contradiction built

Comment: What did you try? Try proving each inclusion separately: to prove $A=B$ you may show $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$.

Comment: Your use of $\forall \epsilon$ is not correct. You are attempting to start with an $\epsilon$ and prove something, but you *actually* want to start with an arbitrary $x \in (a,b)$ and then prove something. The correct way to start is: Let $x \in (a, b)$. Then $x - a > 0$ and $b - x > 0$. Then something something there is an $n$ for which $x \in [a + \frac 1n, b - \frac 1n]$. (Yes I'm being intentionally vague here.)

Answer (score 1):

For the first equality, note that since $[a + \frac 1n , b - \frac 1n] \subset (a,b)$ for all $n$, their union cannot be bigger than $(a,b)$. I.e. $$
\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [a+\frac 1n, b-\frac 1n] \subseteq (a,b)
$$
The meatier part is to show the reverse inclusion. Given a point $x \in (a,b)$, prove that $x \in [a+\frac 1n, b-\frac 1n]$ for some $n$.

Comment: I will definitely use the term 'meaty proof' in the future

Comment: I've posted a solution for reverse inclusion, is that look right?